# Chats.findOne(id) returns nothing, but db.chats.findOne(ObjectId(id)) does

Tags: mongodb, collections, meteor, publish-subscribe

In my meteor app, I want to publish a chatmate according to the chat object's members: basically there are two members, the one that is not the current user is the one I want to publish. Here's the code. (`members` is a list which always contains two different user ids)

```
Meteor.publish('chatmate', function(chat_id) {
  var chat = Chats.findOne({_id:chat_id, members: this.userId});
  var chatmate = undefined; // just in case... didn't know any better
  if (chat) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      if (chat.members[i] !== this.userId)
        chatmate = Meteor.users.find(chat.members[i], {fields: {'profile.name': 1}});
    }
  }
  return chatmate;
});
```

(PS: yes, my publication is in the server folder)

My problem is: my first line of code returns `undefined`. But if I go on mongo and type `db.chats.findOne(ObjectId('<mychatsid>'))`, I do get my record in the output, along with its members. Problem is, it seems I cannot use this useful `ObjectId()` method in Meteor!

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you insert these items directly into the mongo shell, or else `mongorestore` them from another database?  By default, Meteor uses strings for `_id`s (although this can be changed by  settings the `idGeneration` option to `"MONGO"` when the Collection is declared, [as discussed here](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_collection)), whilst stand-alone MongoDB uses ObjectIds, which is what you've got here.

To cut a long story short though, you need to [create a new `ObjectID` object](http://docs.meteor.com/#collection_object_id) and search based on that if this is the format your `_id`s are in:

```
Chats.findOne({ _id: new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID(chat_id), members: this.userId });
```